# What is with this css selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having a custom styled checkboxes with image insead of the dom element. It's using this selector. What this selector do? +em is bugging me big time :)

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked+em::before
```

Please help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships

Comment: A liberal helping of whitespace might clear things up: `input[type='checkbox']:checked + em::before`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` is an [*adjacent sibling combinator*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators). So that selector selects the `em` element *immediately* following a checked checkbox. This is as distinct from the *general sibling combinator*, `~`, which would match any following sibling of the `input` even if not right next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Creates a pseudo-element thats is the first child of the em tag before an input element with the attribute type checkbox that is checked.

Comment: This is incorrect. The selector does not specify a "first child" relationship.

Comment: sorry ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched. Turn on shadow dom in the debugger to view.

Comment: Sorry you are incorrect see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: I'd like to redact my down vote but can't unless you edit your post.